# How can I reflect the state changes in the React main component / homepage?

Tags: reactjs, push, render, history

I am new to react and learning the basics from a Udemy Course, How ever I'm badly stuck with some issues, not able to resolve it.

I'm trying to append a new element to the existing array and display the updated array back in the homepage i.e after state change, I want it to be redirected to (Route path= "/" in render function )
Please check my code below.

(For the time being I've manually added 'id' value 3)

### Main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Title from './Title';
import Photowall from './Photowall';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Newphoto from './Newphoto';
```

```
class Main extends Component {
    constructor(){
    super()
    
        this.state ={
        posts : [{
            id: "0",
            description: "beautiful landscape",
            imageLink: "https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/none/path/sa6549607c78f5c11/image/i4eeacaa2dbf12d6d/version/1490299332/most-beautiful-landscapes-in-europe-lofoten-european-best-destinations-copyright-iakov-kalinin.jpg" +
            "3919321_1443393332_n.jpg"
            }, {
            id: "1",
            description: "Aliens???",
            imageLink: "https://s3.india.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/rocket.jpg"
            }, {
            id: "2",
            description: "On a vacation!",
            imageLink: "https://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/img/editorial/2017/08/24/104670887-VacationExplainsTHUMBWEB.1910x1000.jpg"
            }]
        }  
        
           this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
           
    }
handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('new photo added')
        const newlink = event.target.elements.link.value
        const newdesc = event.target.elements.description.value
        const newpost = [{id 3: ,
                    description : newdesc,
                    imageLink : newlink}]
        console.log(newpost)
        console.log(this.state.posts)
        this.setState({posts : this.state.posts.concat(newpost)}, 
                ()  => {console.log(this.state.posts)})
        
    }
    

    render() { 
        return (
            <Routes>
                <Route path= "/" element = {
                    <div>
                    <Title title={'My Gallery'}> </Title> 
                    <Photowall posts = {this.state.posts}
                            onDelete = {this.handleDelete}>

                    </Photowall>
                    </div>}>
                </Route>
                <Route path= "/addanewphoto" element={
                    <div>
                        <Newphoto submit = {this.handleSubmit} ></Newphoto>
                    </div>
                }>
                </Route> 

            
            </Routes>
       )
    }
}
 
export default Main;
```

### Newphoto.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Newphoto extends Component {

    render() { 
        return (
        <div className='form'>
            <div className='form'>
                    <form onSubmit={this.props.submit}>
                        <input type='text' placeholder='Link' name= 'link'></input>  
                        <input type ='text' placeholder='Description' name='description'></input>
                        <button >  Post </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>);
    }
}
 
export default Newphoto;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Many thanks in advance
Aparna